# Can I do this with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to build a fairly simple website and want to find out if I can use Wordpress. The main part of the website will be three dropdown boxes where the first two boxes are populated by fixed lists of data. The last dropdown will be populated based on a specific list based on the selection in the second box. The webpage with the three selections will be submitted and a simple algorithm will run based on these selections and display a webpage based on the output of the algorithm.  The displayed webpage will also be populated by some of the data from the algorithm.

Can I do this with Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmmh, what you describe (3 input boxes with a simple AJAX dependency between submitting a form and outputting some value) doesn't sound like you should use a CMS at all. In your case, I would probably build a simple HTML file, include some AJAX logic using a public JavaScript library like JQuery, and process the form submission with a scripting language like PHP on the server.

Of course you can use Wordpress for any kind of website, but if you don't have real pages with a steady flow of new content, I don't see why you should bother with setting it up.

Comment: That's sort of what I was thinking. Was planning to build it with rails but recently had a friend suggest Wordpress. I don't really know Wordpress so thought I would at least ask. Thanks.

Comment: @weber Yes, I think you will be better off using rails in that case.